# Horizontal scrollbar inside grid

Tags: html, css

I'm creating 2 parts table, that are connected in between. One part can be scrolled only vertically. Second part is much bigger and can be scrolled vertically (they share vertical scrollbar) and horizontally. Those parts are placed in container that have specific height and width.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30vw 70vw;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.left {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.right {
    max-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="column">
       <div>1</div>
       <div>2</div>
       <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
       <div>1</div>
       <div>2</div>
       <div>3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

It is better visible on stackblitz: [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-3azv5q?file=index.html)

Desired result

[image]

Current result

[image]

The code above kind of works, but the scrollbar isn't always visible. It should be stuck to the screen bottom but instead it is stuck to the container bottom. Do you have any idea how to fix this scrollbar?

Comment: Please include your HTML so we can see the full picture.

Comment: Also can you try drawing/making what you want to appear more visual?

Comment: Please consider leveraging the snippet to your full advantage and including a [mcve] that can be run and examined.

Comment: @カメロン Html included

Comment: @FirestarXYZ Image added

Comment: The reason the scrollbar isn't always visible is that `overflow-y` is set to `auto`, which means it will only show when the content is taller than the container. With the current data, it is not. You should use `scroll` as the value if you want it to always be present.

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's not the case. It is not visible because it's at the bottom of container not because it not exist.

Comment: That's not what the code presented here on Stack Overflow shows. That's why we ask for a [mre].

Comment: @HereticMonkey I've included minimal reproducible example and also added stackblitz example with better styling

Answer (score 0):

We can create an outside div `container` which has the property of scrolling vertically, then create two divs inside, only one of which, `scrolly`, that has the property of scrolling vertically.

Just a note, open the snippet in fullscreen for the best representaiton of the code:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

         #scroll{
        width: 1000px;
        height: 190px;
        overflow: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        margin: 0 auto;
        white-space: nowrap
    }

    img{
        width: 300px;
        height: 150px;
        margin: 20px 10px;
        display: inline;
    }

    #container{
        width: 1000px;
        height: 190px;
        overflow: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        margin: 0 auto;
        white-space: nowrap
    }

    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .parent {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .left {
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
        background-color: red;
        width: 40%;
    }

    .right {
        border: 1px solid lightgray;
        background-color: green;
        width: 40%;
    }
```

```html
<div id = 'container' class = 'parent'>
    <div class="left">
        <img src='img/idk.jpg'></img>
    </div>
    <div id='scroll' class="right">
        <img src='img/idk.jpg'></img>
        <img src='img/idk.jpg'></img>
        <img src='img/idk.jpg'></img>
        <img src='img/idk.jpg'></img>
        <img src='img/idk.jpg'></img>
        <img src='img/idk.jpg'></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helped! Let me know if you have any further questions or need clarification :)

Edit: Made so that divs are side by side and have color

Edit: If you open the snippet in a new tab, you should get so that both scrollbars are visible at all times. If you don't want the vertical scrollbar visible, just add .right in front of the :: in the css

Comment: I appreciate your help, but it is not what I wanted to do. There are to rows with separate scrollings. I need 2 columns with one vertical scrolling and separate horizontal scroll that is always visible (sticked to the bottom of the screen). I've updated my post with animation and stackblitz example whre you can see it better

Comment: Try checking now?

Answer (score 0):

Just add change `overflow: auto;` to `overflow: scroll;` on `right`. Then you can use `.right::-webkit-scrollbar` in your CSS to style a scroll bar so it is always visible horizontally and vertically on that div. See below.

Here are the changes I made to your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-3azv5q?file=index.html)

Edit ~ OP wants the `left` div to scroll with `.right` vertically but still have a horizontal scrollbar always visible for x and y-axis.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30vw 70vw;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  max-height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 70px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.left {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.left div {
  height: 300px;
}

.right {
  max-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}

.right div {
  height: 300px;
}

.column {
  min-width: 500px;
}

.right::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: .5rem;
  height: .5rem;
}

.right::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.right::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="left">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <div class="column">
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          <div>1</div>
          <div>2</div>
          <div>3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's almost it, but the problem is that I need to have one vertical scroll to both columns. In the example you've included I have to scroll both columns separately

Comment: @abellay you will need JS.

Comment: @abellay see edits. Bout as best as you can do to make the entire container scroll. But the horizontal scroll bar is at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

maybe not exactly what you wanted but. you should be aware leftContainer and rightContainer css class in my snippet. you can change some width value. if there is anything you are wondering about let me know. I can update answer.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body{
         overflow: hidden; 
         padding: 0;
         margin: 0;
        }
        .wrapper
        {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100vw;
            display: flex;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .leftContainer {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 30%;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: aqua;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }
        .rightContainer{
            height: 100vh;
            width: 70%;
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
              background-color: blueviolet;
              overflow: auto;
        }
        .leftBlocks{
            height: 100px;
            width: auto;
            border: 1px solid red;
            padding: 1px;
            margin: 5px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .rightBlocks{
            height: 400px;
            width: 400px;
            border: 2px solid yellowgreen;
            padding: 2px;
            margin: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: bisque;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .scrollableContainer{
            height: 2000px;
            width: 2000px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="leftContainer">
            <div class="leftBlocks">1</div>
            <div class="leftBlocks">2</div>
            <div class="leftBlocks">3</div>
            <div class="leftBlocks">4</div>
            <div class="leftBlocks">5</div>
            <div class="leftBlocks">6</div>
            <div class="leftBlocks">7</div>
            <div class="leftBlocks">8</div>
            <div class="leftBlocks">9</div>
            <div class="leftBlocks">10</div>
            <div class="leftBlocks">11</div>
            <div class="leftBlocks">12</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rightContainer">
        <div class="scrollableContainer">
            <div class="rightBlocks">1</div>
            <div class="rightBlocks">2</div>
            <div class="rightBlocks">3</div>
            <div class="rightBlocks">4</div>
            <div class="rightBlocks">5</div>
            <div class="rightBlocks">6</div>
            <div class="rightBlocks">7</div>
            <div class="rightBlocks">8</div>
            <div class="rightBlocks">9</div>
            <div class="rightBlocks">10</div>
            <div class="rightBlocks">11</div>
            <div class="rightBlocks">12</div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```